# Google realtime object pool

Tags: google-drive-api, pool, google-drive-realtime-api

This question is a little "meta" for SO, but there doesn't seem to be a better place to ask it...

[According to Google](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/size), realtime collaborative objects are never deleted from the model. So it makes sense to pool objects where possible, rather than not-really-delete them and subsequently create new ones, thus preventing an unnecessary increase in file-size and overhead.

And here's the problem: in an "undo" scenario, this would mean pulling a deleted object out of the trash pool. But "undo" only applies to operations by the local user, and I can't see how the realtime engine could cope if that "deleted" object had already been claimed by a different user.

My question is, am I missing something or wrong-thinking, and/or is there an alternative to a per-user pool?

(It also occurs to me that as a feature, the API could handle pooling deleted objects, automatically minimizing file-bloat.)

Comment: ps, I hope you like the new docs.  Let me know if there are things that are unclear.

Comment: @CherylSimon Since you ask, the deleteMode on an index reference looks in the docs like a (new?) function, but it's a readonly property... so of course the next question is how do you set it?

Comment: Woops.. you can pass it in to registerReference, instead of the boolean, but the docs aren't updated..  We'll fix it, thanks.

Comment: Is this the kind of overview you were looking for? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/

Comment: @CherylSimon Really appreciate the new documentation and inMemoryMode etc. One doc note: I was half way through asking a new question here about always seeing two active collaborators in the debugger, before realizing the same is true in all the screenshots in your documentation, and so it's likely a side-effect of the debugger? A note on the page or somewhere might save confusion/questions.

Comment: Also... where's the best place to put in a Realtime feature request? (Specifically, being able to transfer an indexReference so it refers to a different object)

Comment: The drive developers g+ page is a good spot https://plus.google.com/communities/107264319205603895037 or the issue tracker https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=Type%3DEnhancement+API%3DDrive

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to be very careful about reusing objects in the way you describe.  Its really hard to get right.  Are you actually running into size issues?  In general as long as you don't constantly create and throw out objects, it shouldn't be a big deal.

You can delete the *contents* of the collab object when its not being used to free up space.  That should generally be enough.

(Note, yes, the API *could* theoretically handle this object cleanup automatically.  It turns out to be a really tricky problem to get right, do to features like undo.  It might show up as a future feature if it becomes a real issue for people.)

Comment: On the new docs thing: yes, I like them, but I'm embarrassed to say I didn't know they _were_ new. In the past, the realtime / drive / apps documentation has appeared, shall we say, spread-out? I've yearned for a documentation overview page with links.

Comment: In this case it's definitely likely that in the course of the project, each user would end up deleting and creating several hundred objects, maybe even a few thousand, many of which themselves contain several objects. I haven't noticed any performance hit, nor run up against any size limits, but in this case I think it is worth at least trying a per-user-pool (plus my ocd side is practically screaming at me to do it).

Comment: You are of course welcome to play with it, but in my opinion its probably a premature optimization more likely to bite you with obscure bugs than actually fix anything :)  The place where people get into trouble is when you say, create a new temp collab object with every mouse event as someone drags across the screen...

Comment: Thanks, Cheryl, I'm persuaded. As possible future-proofing, am I at least allowed to dump (emptied) objects in a list? If they're going to stick around anyway it makes sense to be able to get at them, if it's at ~zero net cost...

Comment: That should be ~zero cost, so probably no harm there.  Ideally we'll fix the problem globally before you get around to trying it yourself, but no promises of course :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Cheryl's answer, the one thing that I see as particularly challenging (actually, impossible) is the pulling-an-object-from-the-pool stuff:

Let's say you have a pool of objects, which (currently) contains a single object `O1`.

When a client needs a new object it will first check the pool. if the pool is not empty it will pull an object from there (the `O1` object) and use it, right?

Now, consider the scenario where *two* clients (a.k.a, editors/collaborators) need a new object at the same time. Each of these clients will run the logic described in the previous paragraph. That is: both clients will check whether the pool is empty and both clients will pull `O1` off of the pull.

So, the loosing client will "think" for some time that it succeeded. it will grab an object from the pool and will do some things with it. later on it will receive an event (E) that tells it that the object was actually pulled by another client. At this point the "loosing" client will need to create another object and re-apply whatever changes it did to the first object to this second object.

Given that you do not know if/when the (E) event is going to fire it actually means that every client needs to be prepared to replace every collaborative object it uses with a new one. This seems quite difficult. Making it more difficult is the fact that you cannot do model changes from event handlers (as this will trump the redo/undo stack). So the actual reaction to the (E) event need to be carried out outside of the (E) event handler. Thus, in the time between the receiving of the (E) event and the fix to the model, your UI layer will not be able to use the model.

Comment: Well yes, that's exactly the problem I was expecting, hence the idea of a per-user pool, likely a list within a userId-keyed map.

Comment: How do you decide which user's pool an object lives in?

Comment: The Riddick approach: you keep what you kill. Is it possible there's ambiguity there? Eg: an object would be removed from a list in a compound op, which is either local or not. If it's local, it gets added to the local user

Comment: pool (which is part of the model). It occurs to me there might be ambiguity as to who actually deleted something. If so, I could use the original creator instead. But since the process is just emptying an object then moving it from one list to another, why should it cause more trouble if I think of it as it "deleting" the object? It's not an ideal solution, as it's not a shared pool, but I don't see why it shouldn't at least work.

Comment: @HeyHeyJC - a user can open the same document multiple times. Thus, you need the pool to be per session. Then you run into this problem: what happens when a session dies on you? you end up with objects, in these lists, which will never be recycles. You can then start thinking on a mechanism which reclaims pools of session which were not active for X days. But, as there is no way to know that a session is really dead (for instance, the user might have been offline for X days) you still have the problem I described. Bottom line: as Cheryl said, do you really have a memory consumption problem?

Comment: Itay, many thanks. The two of you have (mostly) persuaded me: see my comment below.